# Getting different JSON values

Tags: python, json, parsing

Currently trying to parse values of various JSON objects.

```
{"TypeA":{"Name":{"SN":837242580698607},"time":"14:20"}}
{"TypeB":{"Name":{"SN":546422114557665},"time":"14:21"}}
```

The problem is that all these objects are separate lines in a text document, and I want to distinguish TypeA and TypeB

```
for file in os.listdir('database/'):
   with open(os.path.join("database/", file)) as fil:
    for line in fil:
            k=json.loads(line)
            #process
```

I want to to be able to do different processing for `TypeA` and `TypeB` but how can I know if what I am parsing is A or B? If I  call `keys()` to get the first name, the order of the keys is mixed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the key is the json data or not. So do:

```
for file in os.listdir('database/'):
   with open(os.path.join("database/", file)) as fil:
    for line in fil:
            k=json.loads(line)
            if "TypeA" in k:
                 #do some processing 
            elif "TypeB" in k:
                 #do some other processing
```